# How do i control validateForm?

Tags: 8, forms

how do i control: `validateForm`

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // form validation here
  // if validation success then proceed to submit
  // else dont submit and send notification to the respective field
}
```

i have done my fields validation inside that method, however, how do i control from there?

how to stop the submit process if the validation failed?
and
how to send notification/error message to the respective field?

Thank you,

Comment: You should share your actual code (at least one example) because that's exactly what happens if you add the validation errors to form state with the corresponding ->setError* methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  if ($values['your_field'] == 'some_forbidden_value') {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('your_field', $this->t('This value is forbidden!'));
   }
}
```

[About setErrorByName().](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetErrorByName/8.2.x)